# Is the sword stance in Like a Dragon: Ishin where swordsmen place their palm flat against the hilt a style of Tennen Rishin-ryū?

Tags: style, sword, japanese, entertainment

In the video game [*Like A Dragon: Ishin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_a_Dragon:_Ishin!), a major plot point is finding information about the *Tennen Rishin* style practiced by members of the Shinsengumi during the Bakumatsu period (1853-1867) in Japan.

One distinct characteristic of the *Tennen Rishin* style in-game is that the starting fighting stance has users place their palm flat against the hilt of their sword. While it is true that the real Shinsengumi practiced the *Tennen Rishin-ryū* style, I couldn't find any evidence of them putting their palm flat against their sword. In fact, I cannot find any sword style that adopts this stance.

Is there any evidence users of the *Tennen Rishin-ryū* style put their palm flat against the hilt of the sword? If not, is there any sword style where this was done?

[image: Character with palm against sword]
<sub>[Image from Sirus Gaming](https://sirusgaming.com/like-a-dragon-ishin-chapter-3-mibu-wolves/)</sub>

Comment: As far as I know this is used to enhance a thrust if you want to penetrate armor since you literally get more behind the thrust. I do not see much sense in it being used in an opening stance and hence suspect it is mere rule of cool. But I lack the actual expertise in Japanese sword styles to answer the specific question, hence I leave it as a comment.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking That is a great observation. I've seen this somewhere before. Just wish I could remember where. Certainly holding one hand open like this is a way to confuse an opponent who is trying to read body language. It's not certain which cut will come, since one hand is free to switch the grip. It's a defensive stance because the sword is pointing at the opponent, but it can become offensive instantly. I'll follow up if I remember where I saw it.

Comment: I was right! I did see this before. It's in Tenshin-Ryu kenjutsu: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/515521488591163518/

Comment: @SteveWeigand In this picture, it is clearly a moment where the tip of the sword had contact, ready to penetrate. I do get the idea of not telegraphing the second grip but tbh, I feel this particular hand position is pretty impractical for getting any good grip fast. 

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking It didn't look like that to me. Of course, we can't see it at the right angle. But his grip is relaxed and open, and his sword is so low as to be almost at the bladder of his opponent. His sword is a little tilted sideways in a receiving hold. Can't tell exactly. But to me this looks like it might be a defensive posture inviting an attack on his open left side. Well, solution is to look up Tenshin-Ryu some more and find out. That ryu is said to be more modern and flashy than classical ryu.

Comment: Found a video showing it in action.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvUm4uZ-Lys
At location 0:30 technique "tsurunokairan". And yes, it appears they are stepping in with it, but keeping too much distance to connect. More like a threat or a decoy. They take the bait and block high, so the next move is to perform a sword slash to the abdomen which is now open. So to me this looks like it can be used as a thrusting technique or a decoy. Both.

Comment: I think Tenshin Ryu is a very flashy, modern style from what I gather. Though, they take their techniques from various other ryu. One would need to explore the origins of this technique further to know how it was used historically.

Comment: @SteveWeigand Can you post that information and video as an answer?